# Straight Line to Text

Tags: code-golf, math, ascii-art

**Input:**

2 numbers, x and y.

**Output:**

Output a text block where x is the width of the text block and y is the height of the text block. Then there will be a straight line going from the top left to the bottom right and to show it, there should be a # where the line should cross.

The # should be generated using the straight line equation, `y = mx + c` where m is the gradient of the line which can be retrieved through making `m` as `y` divided by `x`. `x` is the current line index. `c` is the height intercept and can be found by multiplying the gradient by the `x` value and adding the `y` value. So, in short, it would be `(y/x) * lineIndex + (y/x * x + h)`. This would all be rounded to the nearest position in the current line.

**Rules:**

- there can only be 1 # per line
- it has to be in the form of a string/whatever the equivalent in your language of choice. This has to be able to cover multiple lines as well.
- in text block, after the # there does not need to be more spaces. Just initial ones to offset the #

**Examples:**

(don't mind the `|`, they are where the lines start and stop)

Where x is 9 and y is 1:

```
|        #|
```

Where x is 1 and y is 5:

```
|#|
|#|
|#|
|#|
|#|
```

where x is 9 and y is 5:

```
| #       |
|   #     |
|    #    |
|      #  |
|        #|
```

where x is 5 and y is 9:

```
|#    |
|#    |
| #   |
| #   |
|  #  |
|  #  |
|   # |
|   # |
|    #|
```

where x is 9 and y is 2:

```
|   #     |
|        #|
```

where x is 9 and y is 3:

```
|  #      |
|     #   |
|        #|
```

Edit: More detail in the output. Added 3rd rule. Added 5th and 6th example

Edit2: Fixed errors in the given examples (Sorry!). Revised over the output to make it much clearer v. sorry for any confusion :S

Comment: How exactly is the position of `#` per line determined? How would the output for 9 and 2 look?

Comment: Editted the main post but the position of the `#` should be determined by using the straight line equation, `y = mx + c`. you can find the examples for both 9, 2 and 9, 3 in the post

Comment: You have four examples with `x=9`, and the first one (with `y=1`) is incompatible with the last three (and I'm not convinced that the second one, with `y=5`, is compatible with the last two). The instruction "The straight line should use the straight line equation, y = mx + c" is not sufficiently precise.

Comment: very sorry about all the confusion, hopefully made it clearer now but do let me know if you find anything unclear so i can make it easy to understand.

Comment: Can we choose to output more than 1 # per line if it helps save bytes?

Comment: @Kritixis Lithios What do you mean by that? also can you provide what the output would be if it was allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## C, <s>74</s> 70 bytes

*Thanks to @Johan du Toit for saving 4 bytes!*

```
i;f(x,y){for(i=y;i--;)printf("%*c\n",(int)round((i-y)/(-1.*y/x)),35);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#fcxBCoMwEAXQvaeQQGFGkkoqWYTBm7gRS0pAo0QFg3j1pil0WfJ3nzfzoyUDBw94mtmDbQNZIQgXb91mgN2qoXOMQ2ro5909AawIWIOQ9yrUByJvFNIV00E59dYBFmdRphjQXCIt@7YC65z4Jk0h/VRylVGdVcV19veR1eavXvE9mLF/rVGM0wc)

Comment: Nice! You can save a couple of bytes by using `-1.*y/x` instead of `-y/(float)x`

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 66 Bytes

```
for([,$x,$y]=$argv;$i<$y;)printf("%".round(++$i*$x/$y)."s\n","#");
```

Comment: 1. no need to init `$i`. 2. save 1 byte (and fix) with `printf("%".round(++$i*$x/$y)."s\n","#");`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 77 bytes

```
x=>y=>[...Array(y).keys()].map(a=>" ".repeat(0|((a+1)/(y/x))+.5)+"#").join`
`
```

```js
f=x=>y=>[...Array(y).keys()].map(a=>" ".repeat(0|((a+1)/(y/x))+.5)+"#").join`
`

console.log(f(9)(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>64</s> 63 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @Cole*

```
def f(x,y):[print(' '*round((i+1)*x/y-1)+'#')for i in range(y)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#Pc5BCsMgEIXhvad40IUziaXYkoWBniRkISQWN6ZIC3p6Gyu4mo9/8Ziy7Q6Okso8L@/ow4ck5BCPb9iI/Kh5SLd81TzKi2R3RHj4gGjDa6fMa7F4YhEAGQXNqkorTE2ma1Iwvd27HixWIepsqrN2Pnv7IvFJR8P/tsTlBw)

Comment: Using a list comprehension is 1 byte shorter (tested in Python 3.5.2): `def f(x,y):[print(' '*round((i+1)*x/y-1)+'#')for i in range(y)]`

Comment: @Cole am  I allowed to return garbage (`None`s)? (I thought about yielding the lines, but the output rules seemed to be strictly stdout here)

Comment: Does a function implicitly return the result of the list comprehension? I'm pretty sure if you saved it in a file and ran it (which afaik is the standard way; you'd specify if it had to be done in a REPL) it would only print out the desired output. If I'm wrong then by all means ignore my suggestion.

Comment: @Cole Sorry, my bad. I guess I was confusing it with lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 21 bytes

```
ÆSpºX+1 /(U/V  r)+"#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@3@4Lbjg0K4IbUMFfY1Q/TAFhSJNbSXl//9NFSwVdIMA)

Input is in the format of `y x`. +1 byte for the `-R` flag.

Answer (score 0):

## AWK, <s>55</s> 44 bytes

```
 {for(;++j<=$2;)printf"%*c\n",$1/$2*j+0.5,35}
```

Using hints from @manatwork and the solution from @Steadybox

The previous code is handy as an example of using an `sprintf` within a `printf`

```
{for(;++j<=$2;)printf sprintf("%%%.0fs\n",$1/$2*j),"#"}
```

Example usage:

```
awk '{for(;++j<=$2;)printf"%*c\n",$1/$2*j+0.5,35}' <<< "9 3"
```

Comment: Not verified all test cases, but wouldn't `{for(;++j<=$2;)printf"%*s\n",$1/$2*j+.5,"#"}` do it?

Comment: What case did it fail on? And I've never tried using the `*` with `printf` in `AWK`

Comment: @manatwork It's good to learn new things :)